# DDD: Repository to read and Unit Of Work to write?

Tags: repository, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, ddd-repositories

After going through multiple stack overflow posts and blog articles, I came to this decision that we need [UnitOfWork design](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern to maintain transactional integrity while writing the domain objects to their respective repositories.

However, we do not need such integrity while reading/searching the repository. Given that, is it a good design to separate the purposes of repositories and unit of works, with the former to be used only for reading domain objects and the later to be used only to create/write/refresh/delete domain objects?

Comment: It seems like what you need is to separate read and write models. I suggest that you have a look on this link https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Yes. I have gone through that. The question here is not that I need separate read and write models, the question is that whether it makes sense that readers (Repository) and writers(Unit of work) work independently.

Comment: @Raymond232 If you work with an ORM, the problem is that it will often force the UoW design pattern on you in both cases. The unit of work itself is not distinguishable from the Facade object that allows you to access data.

Comment: Wrapping the ORM in your own Unit of Work abstraction and using it only on the Write side might be better than nothing though.

Answer (score 4):

Eric Evans, Domain Driven Design:

> Implementation (of a repository) will vary greatly, depending on the technology being used for persistence and the infrastructure you have.  The ideal is to hide all the inner workings from the client (although not from the developer of the client), so that the client code ill be the same whether the data is stored in an object database, a relational database, or simply held in memory....
>
> The possibilities of implementation are so diverse that I can only list some concerns to keep in mind....
>
> *Leave transaction control to the client*.  Although the REPOSITORY will insert and delete from the database, it will ordinarily not commit anything.  It is tempting to commit after saving, for example, but the client presumably has the context to correctly initiate and commit units of work.  Transaction management will be simpler if the REPOSITORY keeps its hands off.

That said; I call your attention in particular to an important phrase in the above discussion: *the database*.  The underlying assumption here being that all of the aggregates being modified are stored in such a way that the unit of work can be committed atomically.

When that's not the case -- for example, if you are storing aggregates in a document store that doesn't promise atomic updates of multiple documents, then you may want to consider making this separation explicit in your model, rather than trying to disguise the fact that you are trying to coordinate multiple commits.

It is entirely reasonable to use one set of repositories for your read use cases, which are distinct from those used in your write use cases.  In other words, when we have different *semantics*, then we should have a different interface, the implementations of which can be tuned as necessary.

Comment: The way I see, let's say I separate reading to repositories and writing to unit of works. In that case, reading can be done as many times as you want, whereas writing happens as part of a usecase, where each use case is represented by a unit of work. So, to complete a use case, you submit the writes/updates etc to the UOW which ultimately commits it. 

Is this right?